# When using next-themes, the fonts keep using the prefer-color-scheme even when toggling between light/dark themes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, darkmode

I'm using Next.js to put together a personal website and wanted to use the `next-themes` library to implement dark/light mode toggling. I've added a button to toggle the website between modes on my Navbar, but when toggling to light mode, the font colors continue to use the dark mode settings. (dark mode looks perfectly fine).

When inspecting, I've noticed that it seems to be caused by this style, which I cannot figure out how to override:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)
.dark:text-gray-100 {
    \--tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(243 244 246 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
```

[Dark Mode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r63HZ.png)

[Light Mode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFR76.png)

Here is the code I am using for my `ThemeButton` component (which works its way into my 'Layout' component):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes';

export default function ThemeButton() {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  const changeTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <button
      aria-label='Toggle Dark Mode'
      type='button'
      className='w-10 h-10 p-3 rounded focus:outline-none'
      onClick={changeTheme}
    >
      {mounted && (
        <span>Change Theme</span>
      )}
    </button>
  );
}
```

And here is my `_app.js` component:

```
import '@components/styles/globals.css';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes';
import Layout from '@components/components/Layout';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider defaultTheme='light' attribute='class' enableSystem= 'false'>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Been stuck on this for quite some time now.

I've tried reading through the next themes documentation and updating the attributed in the `<ThemeProvider\>` wrapper in the `_app.js` file. I've also tried researching where the `prefer-colors-scheme` styling is coming from and how to override it (although I'm not sure I want to completely override it, as I would want the user's system to dictate the first theme)